# Storing arabic letters to phpMyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin, arabic

I'm inserting data from a JAVA desktop application(JDBC) to a mysql database.
Data has some arabic words. When browsing table data using phpmyadmin interface I just have interrogation marks "????????????". What can I do to solve that problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: Is the problem in the database or in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @EJB: The problem was coming from the Mysql my.ini file. Will post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this 2 lines in my.ini file `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\my.ini` in [mysqld] category:

```
   [mysqld]
//you will find surely some data/lines in [mysqld] category, just add the following lines
    character-set-server=utf8
    collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your PhpMyAdmin then change the collation of your database to `cp1256_general_ci` then go to table options and also set the collation as `cp1256_general_ci` and so the collation for the field that may contain Arabic words to the same..